# String Translation in WPML translates too much

Tags: wordpress, language-translation, wpml

I have an issue with string translation in WPML. I have created a site in Hong Kong language, but I don't want that site translated right now, just want to keep the languages the same as the default language.

My issue is that some strings are translated automatically by WPML. Anyone out there who know how to fix this?

Comment: just remove the other language that you do not want to see from your WPML settings

Comment: Where in the wpml settings can I remove that language. I still want the visitors to have option to go to my HK site.

Comment: Just want my HK language to be english (as my default language) - not Chinese.

Comment: delete all the translations you have and in settings choose show default language if there is no translation